# Change in Acceleration to Elapsed Time

Tags: kinematics, jerk

I am designing an algorithm. The problem statement is relatively straightforward. You are given some initial state (initial velocity and initial acceleration) as well as a target acceleration and a displacement over which this target acceleration must be reached.

I need to know how long it would take to linearly ramp acceleration (with respect to time) from the initial acceleration to the final acceleration in that distance. That is to say: what constant jerk and time interval would ramp acceleration appropriately over the given distance?

I have so far gone through the following reasoning:

given that jerk is constant we have $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta t} = J \implies \Delta a = J \Delta t$

Thus if our given displacement is $d$ we have

$$d = v_0t + \frac{1}{2}a_0t^2 + \frac{1}{6}Jt^3 = v_0t + \frac{1}{2}a_0t^2 + \frac{1}{6}\Delta a t^2 $$

And from here I solve the quadratic to get a root for $t$ that would correspond to the displacement $d$ (at which point I could solve for $J$ as well)... Only problem is that this is not working.

Am I doing this completely wrong? Is this problem solvable and how would you go about it? I feel like this should have a distinct and real solution but I am quite stuck.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you have a typo.  The last exponent on t should be a 3, not a 2.

Comment: You have a cubic in $t$. Not quadratic. And your solution will depend on $J$. For each $J$ there’s a different $t$